# Training Inception V2 from scratch - diverging

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

As a learning exercise, I'm training the Inception (v2) model from scratch using the [ImageNet dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/imagenet-object-localization-challenge) from the Kaggle competition. I've heard people say it took them a week or so of training on a GPU to converge this model in this same dataset. I'm currently training it on my MacBook Pro (single CPU), so I'm expecting it to converge in no less than a month or so.

Here's [my implementation](https://github.com/formigone/tf-imagenet/blob/master/models/inception_v2.py) of the Inception model. Input is 224x224x3 images, with values in range [0, 1].
The learning rate was set to a static 0.01 and I'm using the stochastic gradient descent optimizer.

#### My question

After 48 hours of training, the training loss seems to indicate that it's learning from the training data, but the validation loss is beginning to get worse. Ordinarily, this would feel like the model is overfitting. Does it look like something might be wrong with my model or dataset, or is this perfectly expected, since I've only trained 5.8 epochs?

[image]

My training and validation loss and accuracy after 1.5 epochs.

---

[image]

Training and validation loss and accuracy after 5.8 epochs.

---

[image]

Some input images as seen by the model, as well as the output of one of the early convolution layers.